# Share localStorage between web and mobile browsers

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, local-storage

is it possible to persist a string to localStorage or similar alternatives on chrome web browser for example and later access it from the same chrome user in the chrome mobile browser?

The only connection between both is a logged in user, I can't store it using backend.

Any help really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

localStorage doesn't work that way. I don't have experience with this but there's a `chrome.storage` api that may suit your needs https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/

From what I can see though, this involves creating a chrome extension, which your users would likely need to install.

If you can't store data like that in the backend your options will be very limited to persist any kind of state across devices.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't access chrome.storage outside of the extension that's why I can't use this.